# Scheduling the execution of a PHP script that will take place once

Tags: php, mysql, database, cron

I'm a bit stuck trying to create a loan simulator on PHP and Mysql (running on Windows 10 so far).

It is not about tasks repeating over time, but simply deducting loan principal plus interest on a certain future date.

So the user submit let's say a form requesting $100 for 12 months with 10$ interest, so in one year the corresponding DB row will become $90.

I've learned about crons but I'm not sure if that would be useful here since it is required that the due date is generated dynamically as the user requests the loan.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this, if you run a script every day with cron - or in case of windows with task scheduler - which checks your db, and sets every row to the correct amount, where the interest is due.

Comment: That sounds like a gret approach. Thanks!